# FloatingActionButton usando RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, floatingactionbutton

Sempre quando arrasto o FloatingActionButton, o mesmo sempre volta para o canto superior esquerdo. Mesmo usando o RelativeLayout. Estou usando o AndroidStudio 3.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Andre, você precisa fixar o button nas margens.

Assim funciona.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Aconselho a usar o ConstraintLayout para fazer suas telas. Da uma googada